# Entity Framework code first determine if a Database is compatible

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

Our project contains two applications accessing the same Database using the same model.
Both applications use the same bootstrapping mechanism, which will drop the database and recreate it if the database is not compatible with the model. It uses following code:

```
    private bool DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanged(TContext context)
    {
        if (context.Database.Exists())
        {
            if (context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(throwIfNoMetadata: true))
            {
                return false;
            }

            context.Database.Delete();
        }

        var createDatabaseCollationInterceptor = new CreateDatabaseCollationInterceptor(Constants.Database.COLLATION);
        DbInterception.Add(createDatabaseCollationInterceptor);
        context.Database.Create();
        DbInterception.Remove(createDatabaseCollationInterceptor);

        return true;
    }
```

The second application only uses a subset of the model of the first and when calling the above function `context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(throwIfNoMetadata: true)` returns false and the database is being dropped.

[CompatibleWithModel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.compatiblewithmodel(v=vs.113).aspx) returns true if:

```
For Code First the model is considered compatible if the model is stored in the database in the Migrations history table and that model has no differences from the current model as determined by Migrations model differ
```

**Question**: How can I determine if the model is compatible (which I know it is) if it only contains a subset of the entire model?

[Edit] Some words about the architecture

- Application 1 exposes a RESTful API (consumed by the frontend)
- Application 2 exposes SOAP endpoints (the reason to create a second application for this is to not mix the stacks)
- Application 1 consists of 5 modules (a module is a logical functionality spanning full stack from data access to UI)
- Application 2 references 2 modules of Application 1 (only the ones it needs)
- Modules have no reference onto entities from other modules
- A common DB context is being used to initialize the DB while keeping the entitiy definitions decoupled from each other. This is true for all modules except a common Base module

[Edit2] Added workflow describing interaction of applications using SharedTables
[image]

Comment: AFAIK (but I could be wrong) from EF's perspective, those are 2 models. I'd have the DataAccess torn out of the two applications into its own assembly, that is referenced by both applications, so they actually _share_ one single model (database).

Comment: @Fildor they actually do. But the application has been built in a modular way, where each of the 5 modules register their own model which live within the module. The second application only references two out of the five modules of the main application. Which results in this behavior.

Comment: Can you give an outline of the overall architecture in the question? And also how you perform creation / application of migrations?

Comment: It makes little to no sense to have one application(module?) drop an incompatible if it is only using a subset of the model. That would always trigger a second drop from any module using the full model. Is this really your intent?

Comment: @Fildor I've added the main points of the architecture which seem relevant in this context.

Comment: @Tewr You're absolutely right. I'd like to detect with app2 (not module!) that it accesses a compatible model and work with it

Comment: I will reiterate my first comment a bit differently, as you did not really answer it: Is it your intent that the external application will delete and recreate the database should it not be compatible? It seems odd.

Comment: @Tewr It is not a must but I don't mind if it does, because this principal is only being applied in the dev environment. When installing for production SQL scripts are being ran to create tables (including migration history), insert data and add constraints. As the  shown DB initialization code has been written by a partner company, I'd like to reduce changes to a minimum in this layer.

Answer (score 0):

When using code first, the simplest way of enabling co-habitation several models on the same database us to use [separate migration history tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456841).

TL;DR from the linked article: For each separate model, create a new class like this

```
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations.History;

namespace CustomizableMigrationsHistoryTableSample
{
    public class MyHistoryContext : HistoryContext
    {
        public MyHistoryContext(DbConnection dbConnection, string defaultSchema)
            : base(dbConnection, defaultSchema)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            // "MigrationHistory" would have to be renamed for each subset model
            modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().ToTable(tableName: "MigrationHistory", schemaName: "admin");
            modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().Property(p => p.MigrationId).HasColumnName("Migration_ID");
        }
    }
}
```

and add it to your setup:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace CustomizableMigrationsHistoryTableSample
{
    public class ModelConfiguration : DbConfiguration
    {
        public ModelConfiguration()
        {
            this.SetHistoryContext("System.Data.SqlClient",
                (connection, defaultSchema) => new MyHistoryContext(connection, defaultSchema));
        }
    }
}
```

I have used this approach to strongly separate runtime of a limited interface (i.e front-end/public api) from an administrative interface(back-end api), to limit bug/attack surface. I recommend doing some kind code-sharing on the subset of the models to avoid schema drift.

I have never tried this is your particular scenario (completely dropping an incompatible database), so some tweaking is probably needed. You will need to do something like `Add-Migration Initial -IgnoreChanges` when setting up the separate models (at least the subset ones) to existing database, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25957822/entity-framework-code-first-migration-strategy-with-existing-database) for more on this.

Comment: Is it really required to use different migration histories when App2 only uses a subset of the model of App1? I've added a schema describing the workflow which might help to clarify the workflow.

Comment: `CompatibleWithModel` simply compares equality of two xml (Edmx) documents: The one in your migration table, and the one it can generate from itself. It will not try to check if one model is a subset of the other model. The model/tooling is not that expressive to do it automatically. There is no way for you to pass a parameter saying "Im a subset and just not a migration behind? ".

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for. Seems the easiest would be to disable this check when ran from App2 and solve the issue by organizing ourselves to always initialize the DB by running App1 first.