# How to create migrations from an existing database

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

Hello i am faced with the following problem
I have a database up and running on a remote server.I am trying to start migrations since i will update it alot in the future.
However when i running the commands:

```
Add-Migration Initial
Update-Database Initial
```

> There is already an object named 'Files' in the database.

I get an error that says the table already exists.
I have followed this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25957822/entity-framework-code-first-migration-strategy-with-existing-database) that says that i have to clear up the `Up` and `Down` methods , create an empty migration and apply it.That does not work.
It also says to change the `Configuration` file.I have no such file generated.

So what is the correct steps in order to start migrations on an existing database ?

Comment: Did you create migrations for all existing tables and schema before creating a new migration (i.e. is running Update-Database on empty DB going to create the same full structure as on your remote server?)

Comment: have you tried to scaffold the database with a db first approach? https://entityframeworkcore.com/approach-database-first

Comment: @rsobon I have run the script and yes it created a migration for all tables.I then created a new migration , emptied the `Up` and `Down` and applied to it.